# Replace in variable a href address

Tags: javascript

I am beginner web developer.
I have small problem with my code:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-item');

    if(nodes != undefined && nodes !=''){
      var first = nodes[0];
      console.log('xxxxxx' , first);
    }
```

It's return me:

```
[Log] xxxxxx
<li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Home </a>
</li>
```

I need check:

1. if a href is "Home" then replace href from "#/" to "/dashboard"
2. if a href is not "Home" then show console.log('not find').

How can I make it?

I have dynamic string. For example:

```
<li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Home </a>
</li>

<li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/dogs" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Dogs </a>
</li>

<li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/calls" class="router-link-" target="_self"> calls </a>
</li>

<li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/catds" class="router-link-" target="_self"> cats </a>
</li>
```

I need replace URL ONLY for Home

Comment: You mean if user is currenly viewing "Home" Page, then change the href of a tag to /dashboard?

Comment: No, I have this string from PHP: <li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Home </a>
</li>. I need change url (if it's home url)  from "#/" to "/dashboard". :)

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written assuming that `<a href="#/">Home </a>` will always be first in order. If you're going to change its order, you'll will have to change the index for nodes inside if block.

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".breadcrumb-item");

if (nodes.length > 0) {
  const first = nodes[0].firstElementChild;

    first.href = "/dashboard";
    console.log(first);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yours answer is wrong. I updated my first post

Comment: @traks You want the tag like this <a href="/dashboard">Home </a>?

Comment: If JS found this: <li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="#/" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Home </a>
</li>
 I Need this:

Comment: <li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item">
<a href="/dashboard" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Home </a>
</li>

Comment: This <a> tag always going to be the first element or are you going to change its order?
I'll give you the code according to this!

Comment: This code not working. I have on webpage (vue): <div class="c-subheader px-3"><ol class="breadcrumb border-0 mb-0"><li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#/" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Home </a></li><li role="presentation" class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#/tasks" class="router-link-active" target="_self"> Zlecenia </a></li><li role="presentation" class="active breadcrumb-item"><span>Edytuj zlecenie</span></li></ol></div> and your code show: Not find

Comment: @traks check now!

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct. Maybe the following gives you a clearer understanding:

```
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-item');

    if (nodes.length > 0) {
      const first = nodes[0].firstElementChild;
      let currentUrlTitle = first.text.trim().toLowerCase();
  
      if (currentUrlTitle == 'home') {
        console.log(first.text);
        first.href = '/dashboard';
        console.log(first.href);
      } else {
        console.log(currentUrlTitle);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).